# Powering down external hard drive, flash drive, etc using the command line in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I always thought that to safely remove a device that had been mounted was to use the `umount` command and until recently when I switched to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I noticed that there was the ability to safely remove the device which struck my curiosity.

I dug around a number of posts and found that `umount` apparently doesn't mean I can safely remove the device because it doesn't power down the device. I know there is the option to `eject`. Now this is my understanding after scouring the Internet. References include:

- [The “Unmount”, “Eject” and “Safely Remove Drive” dilemma](http://ubuntutalk.tumblr.com/post/346018554/the-unmount-eject-and-safely-remove-drive-dilemma)
- ["eject" / "unmount" / "safely remove drive" - which is better?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1471030)

  1. umount only unmounts a single partition on the device
  2. safely remove unmounts all partitions on the device and powers down the device
  3. eject is used to media such as CDs, DVD, etc

I then came across an [article](http://elliotli.blogspot.com/2009/01/safely-remove-usb-hard-drive-in-linux.html) but found the process convoluted and I think I finally hit pay dirt when I came across the command `udisks` e.g. `udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1 && udisks --detach /dev/sdb`

What confuses me is (aside from whether `umount` actually means it is safe to remove the device without data loss and whether I need to use the command `sync` prior to it as well as that the device has powered down which safely remove seems to achieve) is why do I have to use `/dev/sdb` followed by `--detach` as opposed to `/dev/sdb1`

Comment: Related: [Why does umount /dev/sdc1 for example not remove/eject an external harddrive?](http://superuser.com/questions/429256/why-does-umount-dev-sdc1-for-example-not-remove-eject-an-external-harddrive)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/dev/sdb` is the whole device. `/dev/sdb1` is one partition on that device.

While you could use a disk without partitioning it, that's rather unusual (outside of RAID setups, but then you make the filesystems on the raid device nodes, not the physical device nodes).
It doesn't really make sense to try to detach (physically remove) a single partition – you want to remove the whole device (that can contain multiple partitions), not just one partition of that device.

Unmounting a partition will synchronize the filesystem, so calling `sync` before `unmount` is not necessary.
Calling `udisks --detach` on the device checks that you have no filesystems mounted on that device (you should make sure that that call does indeed succeed), and will perform an "orderly shutdown", which is always preferable to a "pull the plug" approach, regardless of whether that particular device does anything special.

Comment: I had no idea that just /dev/sdb represents the entire device which I presume represents all partitions. Is that correct? So I could just run the command as `udisks --unmount /dev/sdb && udisks --detach /dev/sdb` if I want to unmount all the partitions? Makes so sense to just unmount one partition if multiple partitions exist.

Comment: How do you also make sure that the call `udisks --detach` does succeed?

Comment: No, unmounting `/dev/sdb` won't work. You need to unmount each mounted partition, and look at/parse the output of the commands.

Comment: Sorry, don't quite follow what you mean by look at or parse the output the commands? Shouldn't I unmount each partition and then run the command `udisks --detach /dev/sdb`?